# SAS: Marking next and previous observations with conflicts

Tags: events, sas, lag, lead

I want to create dummies in SAS. My plan is, everytime AnnouncementDate ne . I want to make a variable called event=2 and the next one also (event=2) as well as the five previous observations 1
And all this flagged if the Previous 5 observations and the day after the announcement date are not empty. 
and in a by class (by stock for example)

output data

```
date announcementdate event conflict
1115 . . .
2115 . . .
3115 . . .
4115 . . .
5115 . . .
6115 . 1 .
7115 . 1 .
8115 . 1 .
9115 . 1 .
10115 . 1 .
11115 1115 2 .
12115 . 2 .
13115 . .
14115 . 1 .
16115 . 1 .
17115 . 1 .
18115 . 1 .
19115 . 1 .
20115 20115 2 
21115 . 1 Y
21115 . 1 Y
22115 22115 2 Y
23115 . 2 Y
24115 . .
25115 . .
```

If this now switches to the next stock, it should start over and not take the previous observations into account.

My current code does a lead term as I merge just the event column with firstobs=2. Anyways this 5x lag bothers me as well as the conflict when there are observations before.

```
data want1 ; set have;;
if announcementdate ne . then event=0;
run;

data want2; merge want1 (firstobs=2) want1 (keep=event rename= (event=event2)); 
if event2=0 then event=0; 
if event2=0 then event=event2;
run;
```

Thankful for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to this is to first parse the dataset to work out what the ranges would be, using `_n_` as the indicator (rather than the id).  Then you can build a simple start-end range and use that to build a format (well, two, one for 1 and one for 2).

Then, parse *that* dataset with a look-ahead merge (to grab the next value of start) and see if a conflict exists; then use your logic to define another format for conflict markers.  My example includes logic for this; it may or may not match your exact needs though, so you might have to think a bit more about this logic and modify this some as it's fairly specific.

Then you just apply the format using `_n_` as the input.  Make sure the original dataset doesn't get sorted, of course.

Here's the complete code.

```
data have;
input date announcementdate event_want conflict_want $;
datalines;
1115 . . .
2115 . . .
3115 . . .
4115 . . .
5115 . . .
6115 . 1 .
7115 . 1 .
8115 . 1 .
9115 . 1 .
10115 . 1 .
11115 1115 2 .
12115 . 2 .
13115 . . .
14115 . 1 .
16115 . 1 .
17115 . 1 .
18115 . 1 .
19115 . 1 .
20115 20115 2 .
21115 . 1 Y
21115 . 1 Y
22115 22115 2 Y
23115 . 2 Y
24115 . . .
25115 . . .
;;;;
run;

data for_fmt;
  set have nobs=nobs;
  length fmtname $16;
  fmtname = 'eventf';

  if _n_=1 then do;   *HLO='o' gives the 'other' value;
    start=.;
    end  =.;
    label = ' ';
    hlo='o';
    output;
  end;
  hlo=' ';

  if not missing(announcementdate) then do;
    start = max(1,_n_-5);
    end   = max(1,_n_-1);
    label='1';
    output;
    start = _n_;
    end   = min(_n_+1,nobs);
    label='2';
    output;
  end;
run;  *now we have a dataset of the ranges - but they overlap;

data for_fmt_conflicts;

  merge for_fmt(in=a) for_fmt(in=_in_next firstobs=2 keep=start rename=start=next_start); *look-ahead merge;
  retain new_start conflict_marker;
  if hlo='o' then do;    *again the 'other' row;
    output;
    fmtname='conflictf';
    output;
  end;
  else if end gt next_start and (_in_next) then do;   *if the next row will be a conflict, adjust the end back one and indicate where next should start;
    end = end-1;
    new_start = end+1;
    conflict_marker=1;
    output;
  end;
  else if conflict_marker=1 then do;  *if this is a conflict row type 1;
    start = new_start;
    output;
    fmtname='conflictf';
    label  ='Y';
    output;
    conflict_marker=2;
  end;
  else if conflict_marker=2 then do;  *if this is the 2s for a conflict row;
    output;
    fmtname='conflictf';
    label  ='Y';
    output;
    conflict_marker=0;
  end;
  else output;
run;
proc sort data=for_fmt_conflicts;  *must sort to get fmtnames grouped together;
  by fmtname start;
run;
proc format cntlin=for_fmt_conflicts;  *import formats;
quit;

data want;  *now apply formats;
  set have;
  event = put(_n_,eventf.);
  conflict = put(_n_,conflictf.);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Tweaked it a little but this is fantastic!!

Comment: Well, there's one thing. I can do whatever I want but it keeps giving me the Error: Start is greater than end.